# Finding P(X-Y>0) For two discrete random variables that are independent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A and B can independently generate positive integers:

A generates positive integer n with probability
$\frac{\alpha}{3^n}$, where $\alpha$
is a constant.
B generates positive integer n with probability
$\frac{\beta}{n!}$, where $\beta$
is a constant.

(a) Find the probability that the number generated by A is larger than the number generated by B.

(b) Find the probability that the number generated by A is smaller than the number generated by B.

I found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be 2 and $\frac{1}{(e-1)}$ then i'm stuck as i tried to do P(A-B>0) but I do not know how to calculate that. Any hints?

Edit:
I did $ 1-P(X<=Y) =
1-P(X<=K | Y=K) P(Y=K)$
and calculated $1- 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{2}{3^i}*\frac{1}{k!(e-1)}$

Doing the summation part:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(e-1)}(1-\frac{1}{3^k}) = \frac{1}{(e-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{k!3^n}$

Using $e^x-1$,

$\frac{1}{e-1}(({e-1})-(e^{1/3}-1))$

Therefore $1-P(X<=Y) = 1 -(1 - \frac{e^{1/3}-1}{e-1})$

Can somebody help to factcheck this? Been stuck for hours at this problem :(

Comment: $P(A-B>0)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m>n} P(A=m)P(B=n)$

Comment: Hi! I did derive that for my working but how do u calculate the summation where m>n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answers for $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = (e-1)^{-1}$ are correct.

Your answer $$\Pr[A > B] = \sum_{b=1}^\infty \Pr[A > b]\Pr[B = b] = \sum_{b=1}^\infty \sum_{a=b+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^a} \frac{1}{(e-1)b!} = \frac{e^{1/3} - 1}{e-1}$$
is also correct.

What remains is to compute $\Pr[A < B]$.  To do this, it suffices to observe
$$\Pr[A > B] + \Pr[A = B] + \Pr[A < B] = 1,$$
and that
$$\Pr[A = B] = \sum_{a=1}^\infty \Pr[A = a]\Pr[B = a] = \sum_{a=1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^a} \frac{1}{(e-1)a!},$$
which is slightly easier than directly computing another double sum.